# Is it possible for a DBA to get around Azure Temporal Tables?

Tags: azure-sql-database

[Azure has support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) for temporal tables.

It seems to do this by copying data to a history table when an update is made.

Is it possible to work around these features?

e.g.

- What happens if I issue an update or delete to the history table?
- Can I turn the feature off, make edits and turn it on again?

I'm asking from the point of view of a regulator that wants to know for sure whether the data I see now is the same as when I looked at it 7 years ago and hasn't been tampered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can't change the history.  However, a sufficiently powerful user can disable the temporal logic and then modify the data if desired (to do maintenance of otherwise).  You can use the role-based permission model to disallow that path or use auditing to watch the scenarios you wish to enable them to do.